# Why do I get a 401 status code from the discord api?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, request

I'm trying to validate discord token, sending requests to the discord api, this was working but for some reason it stopped, this is my code:

```
def validate():                           
 headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'authorization': "my_token_here"}            
 request = requests.get("https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/library", headers=headers)  
 if(request.status_code == 200):                
  print("\033[32m[+] Valid Token.\033[m")   
 else:                                          
  print("\033[33m[-] Invalid Token.\033[m")
```

I put my bot token and still the status is 401, it was working before, can someone help me and explain what happened

**Edit:**

I noticed that I had placed a slash after library and then I started to receive the unauthorized code 401, even though the token is valid, why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending the call using HTTP and not HTTPS. I'm not sure this will solve the problem, but it might be worth a try.

Difference between HTTP and HTTPS:HTTPS is HTTP with encryption. The only difference between the two protocols is that HTTPS uses TLS (SSL) to encrypt normal HTTP requests and responses. As a result, HTTPS is far more secure than HTTP. A website that uses HTTP has http:// in its URL, while a website that uses HTTPS has https://.

Also, make sure that all parts of the address are spelled correctly. And if the API you are referring to belongs to you and make sure it is defined properly.

Comment: Same error, and the api is from discord, it was working before, I don't know what happened